# How to select one object from a NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays

First of all Merry Christmas to everyone!!! Currently I have a NSArray that has parsed content in it. When I do a NSLog of the array it prints out 20 objects with the parsed content that I needed. Like so:

```
2010-12-24 20:27:32.170 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent
2010-12-24 20:27:32.172 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent1
2010-12-24 20:27:32.172 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent2
2010-12-24 20:27:32.173 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent3
2010-12-24 20:27:32.173 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent4
2010-12-24 20:27:32.173 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent5
2010-12-24 20:27:32.174 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent6
2010-12-24 20:27:32.175 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent7
2010-12-24 20:27:32.176 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent8
2010-12-24 20:27:32.176 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent9
2010-12-24 20:27:32.177 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent10
2010-12-24 20:27:32.177 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent11
2010-12-24 20:27:32.177 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent12
2010-12-24 20:27:32.179 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent13
2010-12-24 20:27:32.179 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent14
2010-12-24 20:27:32.180 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent15
2010-12-24 20:27:32.180 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent16
2010-12-24 20:27:32.181 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent17
2010-12-24 20:27:32.181 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent18
2010-12-24 20:27:32.190 TestProject[48914:298] SomeContent19
```

However, I don't need every object at once. I need to be able to pick out one object at a time so I can put each object into a string of its own. If anyone knows of an easier way to do this then what I'm trying to please let me know. Anyways, I need to be able to choose just one object depending on what object I need. For example, let's say I only need object #5 and not all the array, how can this be done so I can put it into a string? I'm thinking I might have to use the index feature but I'm not sure how to set it up properly. Here is my NSArray that I'm working with:

```
NSArray* myArray = [document selectElements: @"div.someContent"];
NSMutableArray* results = [NSMutableArray array];
for (Element* element in myArray){
    NSString* snipet = [element contentsSource];
    [results addObject: snipet];
    NSLog(@"%@", snipet);
}
NSLog(@"%i",myArray.count);
```

I've already spent several hours trying to achieve this but my knowledge with array's is limited even with me reading the documentation. :-( Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To retrieve the first object in an array:

```
id obj = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

To retrieve a random object in an array:

```
id obj = [array objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(array.count)];
```

See [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/) and the [`arc4random_uniform` man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/arc4random_uniform/).

Comment: The app keeps crashing. There is a warning stating that 'NSString' may not respond to '-contentsSource' and or 'NSString' may not respond to '-objectAtIndex'

Comment: Here is the code I'm using NSLog(@"%@", [snipet objectAtIndex:5]);

Comment: @OSX Use `[myArray objectAtIndex:5]`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before and it kept printing out all the objects and I thought it was wrong but I had it with in the {} so it repeated it 20 times. My fault, Thanks Jacob!

Comment: Jacob saves the day again! +1

Answer (score 3):

Check the documentation for `-objectAtIndex:`

Comment: Is there anyway you can show me an example piece of code? I already knew I probably had to use that but never could get it working correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Element *snippet = [results objectAtIndex:5];
```

See [NSArray programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-BBCCJBIF) for details on how to use NSArrays.